# Split one row into two of data frame based on certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[Input and Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dPoq.png)

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Device': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'Revenue': [1000, 2000, 5000],
    'Sales': [200, 300, 400]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I have data frame and want to split based on the x condition. The output is also a data frame.

Condition:
If X=40% then split B into two row like B1& B2 and further columns like In Revenue, 40% of 2000 in B1 and 60% of 2000 in B2. similarly for Sales.
But No split if x<40.
Split "B" only wherever found in Device columns.

Please help to get this output.

Comment: Hi deeplearning! Welcome to stackoverflow. Generally speaking, people here really really dislike it when people post questions with photos of their data and/or code (because, what am I meant to do with that?). You'll have a much better reaction if you just copy and paste the important stuff into your question

Comment: also, can you clarify why B splits and not A or C?

Comment: This is what i am looking for,  Where ever B found in column 'Device', it will split into two.B1 and B2

Comment: What is `X` in the question?

Comment: X is an input variable.

Comment: So it's just a flag? `X = 0.04 ; if X == 0.04 ; # do something`? It has no direct link with the shown data? How how do you chose `B`? Is this fixed? The way your question is phrased it seems that everything is fixed and `X` is irrelevant, you seem to just want to duplicate `B` in two rows with 40/60% of the original value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*This solution determines X externally so may not speak directly to the use case*)

Here's a function that splits chosen rows (`split_label`) in chosen columns (`cols_to_split`) on a chosen percentage (`percentile`) and adds suffixes (`1`,`2`) to the chosen label column (`label_col`).

I chose to create two dfs then concatenate as this enables vectorized splitting. May not be the best solution?

I've stuck it in a function for generalization, but you can of course just implement the function body once with literals

```
import pandas as pd
    
def expand_and_split_df(df: pd.DataFrame, percentile: float, label_col: str, split_label: Any, cols_to_split: list[str]):
    """Partition and expand DataFrame rows based on a percentile. 
      Only apply to rows determined by a condition on the label column. 
      Suffix labels in a label column with '1' and '2'."""

    # Checks for valid percentile split
    if(percentile >1) or (percentile <=0):
        raise ValueError("Percentile needs to be between [0,1]")

    df_rows_to_keep = df[df[label_col]!=split_label].copy()
    df_rows_to_split = df[df[label_col]==split_label].copy()

    # One df for one half of the split
    df1 = df_rows_to_split.copy()
    df1[cols_to_split] = df1[cols_to_split] * percentile
    df1[label_col] = df1[label_col].astype(str) + "1"

    # And another for the other half
    df2 = df_rows_to_split.copy()
    df2[cols_to_split] = df2[cols_to_split] * (1-percentile)
    df2[label_col] = df2[label_col].astype(str) + "2"

    #sort_values not necessary
    return pd.concat([df_rows_to_keep, df1, df2], axis=0).sort_values(label_col)
```

Answer (score 0):

The expected logic is unclear. What I understand is that you have an independent variable `X` that triggers a condition in which you want to duplicate the row with `B` as Device into two rows with 40/60% of the original values.

As the logic is quite non-generic you have to do things manually:

```
X = 0.4
target = 'B'

if X == 0.4:
    tmp = df.set_index('Device')
    df = pd.concat([tmp.drop(target),
                    tmp.loc[[target]*2]
                       .set_axis([f'{target}{i+1}' for i in range(2)])
                       .mul([0.4, 0.6], axis=0)
                   ]).sort_index().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  Device  Revenue  Sales
0      A   1000.0  200.0
1     B1    800.0  120.0
2     B2   1200.0  180.0
3      C   5000.0  400.0
```

Comment: B need to change to B1 and B2.
X is a input variable range from 0 to 1, consider as percentage.

Comment: @deeplearning I forgot about incrementing the name, see update